# IBM Q: How to change my results from hexadecimal to computation basis in 1s and 0s?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

Hey IBM quantum noobie here, Everytime I run my circuits, I get the results graph’s measurement basis (x axis) in hexadecimal form, how do i change this so that the results graph in in the computation basis. (for example the hexadecimal 0xF would turn into the binary number 1111)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you run an experiment on IBM quantum backend, both `job.result().get_counts()` and `job.result().get_memory()` return binary-encoded numbers.
If, however, you got hexadecimal numbers you can use [`Counts`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Counts.html) class to convert them as follows:

```
from qiskit.result import Counts

raw_data = {"0x0": 39, "0x2": 204, "0x3": 617, "0x2E": 3140}
_counts = Counts(raw_data, memory_slots=6)
print(_counts)
```

The result should be:

```
{'000000': 39, '000010': 204, '000011': 617, '101110': 3140}
```

Another option is to use [`ProbDistribution`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.ProbDistribution.html) class, which can be used as follows:

```
from qiskit.result import ProbDistribution

dist = ProbDistribution(raw_data)
print(dist.binary_probabilities())
```